# Сохранение инфы в делфи и ее открытие как все это реализовать

Tags: delphi

Просто у меня надо сделать редактор блок схем как сохрани ть и открыть файлы не знаю

Comment: формат и представление файлов данных известен? Простая работа с файлами: [Работа с файлами в Delphi][1]


  [1]: http://www.delphi-manual.ru/les7next.php

Comment: Попробуй поюзать INI файлы. С ними работать очень легко, особенно в Delphi. Можно даже их использовать вместо какой-нибудь легковесной СУБД, но это только поначалу.

Answer (score 1):

пиши свою структуру хранение в файле. К примеру строка

s:20:20:60 - охначачает S - фигрура квадрат, 20:20 - Х Y координаты верхнего левого угла,  60- размер грани. Также можешь добавить еще хранение по каждой фигуре (объекту) заливку, цвет гранией , тип заливки. Также подумай - хрпанитьь каждый объект с новой строки или принумать разделитель хранения - символ который больше нигде исрользоватся не сможет

В общем как то так - на скоко фантазии у тя хватит)

Answer (score 0):

можешь использовать XML, Ini или свой формат (свой Я бы не советовал)

самое просто это Ini
например:

```
[Lines/Line3/BeginPoint]
From=Point
X=20
Y=20
[Lines/Line3/EndPoint]
From=LineCenter
LineName=Line2  //провести линию к центру линии Line2
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать фабрики и сериализовать.

Answer (score 0):

Откройте текстовым редактором файл ***dfm** и посмотрите как IDE Delphi хранит формы и обьекты на формах, можете смело поступать таким же образом